# Getting the json into map format for implementing angular tree

Tags: javascript, json, angular-material, treeview

I am trying to map a JSON having children nodes into a certain map for mat so that I can implement angular material tree to it.
Here are the JSON and respective map format needed.

```
{
  "id": "Fruit",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "Apple",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "Mac",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": "Fuji",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Mango",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "testMango",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "testTestMango",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Map format needed:

```
dataMap = new Map<string, string[]>([
    ['Fruits', ['Apple', 'Mango']],
    ['Apple', ['Fuji', 'Mac']],
    ['Mango', ['testMango']],
    ['testMango', ['testTestMango']],
  ]);
```

Please help in achieving this..Thanks in advance!!

Comment: NeverMind, i was able to do it....Thanks

Comment: Hi @Abinit Varma...how did you solve it? Can you please share your solution here. Thanks in advance..